# Making a basic 4 function calculator, getting "error c4700: uninitialized local variable 'answ' used"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization

I am getting this error trying to make a basic 4 function calculator.  I am fairly new to c++ so there are probably more mistakes but i mainly want to focus on the error because i cannot compile it.  Thanks for you help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float fadd(float num1, float num2, float answ);
float fsub(float num1, float num2, float answ);
float fmul(float num1, float num2, float answ);
float fdiv(float num1, float num2, float answ);
char contOption();

int main()
{
    float answ, num1, num2;
    char oper, cont;
    cout << "Student name:           Jose Gomez" << endl;
    cout << "Student number:         900724015" << endl << endl << endl;
    do 
    {
    cout << "Please enter first number, operator & second number: ";
    cin >> num1 >> oper >> num2;
    switch (oper)
    {
    case '+':
        fadd(num1, num2, answ); //the 'answ' here is what is giving me the 
                                //error and i do not know how to fix it
        cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
    case '-':
        fsub(num1, num2, answ);
        cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
    case '*':
        fmul(num1, num2, answ);
        cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
    case '/':
        fdiv(num1, num2, answ);
        cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
    default:
        cout << "Sorry, illegal operation.  Only '+', '-', '*', '/' are        allowed" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter first number, operator & second number: ";
    cin >> num1 >> oper >> num2;
}
    cont = contOption();

} while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');


cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

float fadd(float num1, float num2, float answ)
{
    answ = num1 + num2;
    return answ;
}

float fsub(float num1, float num2, float answ)
{
answ = num1 - num2;
return answ;
}

float fmul(float num1, float num2, float answ)
{
answ = num1*num2;
return answ;
}

float fdiv(float num1, float num2, float answ)
{
answ = num1 / num2;
if (num2 == 0)
    cout << "Sorry, divide by 0 is an illegal operation";
else if (num2 != 0)
    return answ;

}

char contOption()
{
char cont;
cout << endl << "Would you like to perform another calculation? (y / n): ";
cin >> cont;
return cont;

}
```

Comment: why does the function take the output variable as an input (and not by reference) when you return the output as well?

Comment: It should be a warning, not an error. Unless you turned on the "treat warnings as errors" option.

Comment: You know `fadd(num1, num2, answ);` doesn't actually change the value of `answ` right?

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to initialize your variables:

```
float answ, num1, num2;
answ = num1 = num2 = 0.0;
```

Otherwise they are undefined. Second, you should add breaks in your switch statement, otherwise you'll be checking every condition and hitting the default condition everytime.

Next, in your functions, you're passing arguments by value rather than by reference. This causes your function to make a copy of the variables you pass in.  So when you try to print the answer after running your calculation, you are attempting to print a non-initialized variable. Passing arguments by reference will actually use the variables you pass in.

Alternatively, you could assign 'answ' the value you return from your functions if you prefer to pass by value, but you aren't doing that.

Here's an example that passes by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fadd(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ);
void fsub(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ);
void fmul(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ);
void fdiv(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ);
char contOption();

int main()
{
    float answ, num1, num2;
    answ = num1 = num2 = 0.0;
    char oper, cont;
    cout << "Student name:           Jose Gomez" << endl;
    cout << "Student number:         900724015" << endl << endl << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter first number, operator & second number: ";
        cin >> num1 >> oper >> num2;
        switch (oper)
        {
        case '+':
            fadd(num1, num2, answ); //the 'answ' here is what is giving me the 
                                    //error and i do not know how to fix it
            cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
            break;
        case '-':
            fsub(num1, num2, answ);
            cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
            break;
        case '*':
            fmul(num1, num2, answ);
            cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
            break;
        case '/':
            fdiv(num1, num2, answ);
            cout << endl << "Answer = " << answ;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Sorry, illegal operation.  Only '+', '-', '*', '/' are        allowed" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Please enter first number, operator & second number: ";
        cin >> num1 >> oper >> num2;
    }

    cont = contOption();

    } while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y');


    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void fadd(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ)
{
    answ = num1 + num2;
}

void fsub(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ)
{
    answ = num1 - num2;
}

void fmul(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ)
{
    answ = num1*num2;
}

void fdiv(float& num1, float& num2, float& answ)
{
    answ = num1 / num2;
    if (num2 == 0)
        cout << "Sorry, divide by 0 is an illegal operation";
}

char contOption()
{
    char cont;
    cout << endl << "Would you like to perform another calculation? (y / n): ";
    cin >> cont;
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this.  Why make them = to 0 if I'm asking the user to give me the input.

Comment: because you're using the answer variable as input rather than output the way your functions are currently set up, it needs to take a pointer or reference to the answer if you want to write to it.

Comment: I'm honestly stuck.  I tried adding "answ = num1 = num2 = 0.0;" but the code just did not work out in general.  Can anyone help with format?